# Android Activity with Abstract Base Class throws a compile error "is not abstract and does not overrid abstract method..."

Tags: java, android

I have a base class that extends ListActivity, that I want to use to implement a lot of common code used on multiple different Activity implementations.

I want to make this base class abstract to enforce implementation of a method on the subclasses.

If I write a base implementation of the method, and override it in the subclasses, everything works fine.

If I make the method abstract, I get the following compile error:

```
XXXX.subapps.athletics.AthleticsNewsActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getListItems() in XXXX.subapps.BaseCategoryListActivity
```

Base Class:

```
public abstract class BaseCategoryListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    ....
    abstract ArrayList<String> getListItems();
    ....
}
```

Example subclass:

```
public class AthleticsNewsActivity extends BaseCategoryListActivity
{
    ....
    public ArrayList<String> getListItems()
    {
       ...implementation details....
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use at least some [basic formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you extend an Abstract Class you need to make the method either abstract in extended class or you need to provide implementations:

```
public abstract class BaseCategoryListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    ....
    public abstract ArrayList<String> getListItems();
    ....
}

public class AthleticsNewsActivity extends BaseCategoryListActivity
{
    ....
    public ArrayList<String> getListItems()
    {
       ...implementation details....
    }
}
```

This should work, note the change of **public modifier**
**overridden method can't have broader visibility specifier**

**Also See**

- [Docs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html)

Comment: My goodness.  And hear I was thinking is was something Android / Activity specific.  I was just missing the obvious and making it more complicated than it was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change access modifier to `public abstract`

You have it listed just as:

`abstract ArrayList<String> getListItems();`

Change it to read:

`public abstract ArrayList<String> getListItems()`

and provide an implementation for it.

Answer (score 1):

The visibility does not match, make both public.

Out of topic: Prefer using interfaces (List) not implementations (ArrayList) in the signature.